# Instruction insertion

Tags: excel, vba, numbers

I have created an invoicing system that creates a new invoice (worksheet) and unprotects the worksheet so that data can be input.  The system has been working great and it took me quite a while to create initially, but one thing i cannot figure out how to do is write vba code to insert an auto increment from the worksheet before it. i.e. auto number (adding one from previous sheet, with the letters "JJ" incorporated.  ie.JJ1234 + 1 = JJ1235) the auto invoice number needs to go into "C10". I just can't figure out where to add the new code and add the numbers?

This is the data i have been using successfully - can anyone assist please?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Worksheets("Activesheet").Copy before:=Sheets("Master")
   ActiveSheet.Name = "NewSheet"
   Dim ws As Worksheet

   Set ws = Worksheets("NewSheet")
   Worksheets("NewSheet").Range("e10") = Now
   ws.Unprotect Password:="password"

   With Sheets("Master")


   End With
   
   ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.BackColor = &H8080FF

End Sub
```

My invoice is one invoice per worksheet. My code creates a new invoice from an 'Activeworksheet', inserts todays date, and then presents itself as a page/worksheet per invoice. I then complete the invoice manually, invoice is auto saved as Invoice number ("c10") and project name. All the data is then inserted into a master sheet on the next available blank line, that saves all selected information per line. It then creates a pdf and files it in my invoice file. It is set so that it notifies me of any duplicate.

Comment: What is the name of *"the worksheet before it"* and where is the auto number located?

Comment: Do you actually have a worksheet with the name `Activesheet`? `Worksheets("Activesheet")`

Comment: I don't have an answer for your problem because many parameters are unclear. I think the way you approach the "invoicing system" is wrong. You need one sheet for data entry and one for saving the records (one line for each invoice)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub FindNextNumber()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim num As Long
    Dim maxNum As Long
    
    'Loop through all worksheets
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Check if the worksheet name matches the format JJxxxx
        If Left(ws.Name, 2) = "JJ" And IsNumeric(Right(ws.Name, 4)) Then
            'Get the number from the worksheet name
            num = CLng(Right(ws.Name, 4))
            'Check if the number is greater than the current max
            If num > maxNum Then
                maxNum = num
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    
    'Add 1 to the max number
    maxNum = maxNum + 1
    
    'Display the result in cell C10 of the Master sheet
    Worksheets("Master").Range("C10").Value = "JJ" & Format(maxNum, "0000")

End Sub
```